# Sum of Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like this,

```
id  state   country name    years
1   ohio        US          steve       2020-08-11
2   delhi       india       priya       2019-09-01
3   ohio        US          alex        2020-07-11
4   NY          US          kristen     2018-06-11
5   hyderabad   india       riya        2019-08-16
6   hyderabad   india       isha        2019-05-04
```

```
select (count(*)) as 'Counts',country, state
from dbo.people
group by country, state
having count(*)>1
```

I have written the above query to count people living in same state

```
counts country      state
2     india         hyderabad 
2      US           ohio
```

could you please help me to write a query that will return the sum of count and then add 1 to the sum,
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to add 1 to a `COUNT`, then just `+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your initial query as a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to sum their counts :

```
with initial_query as (
  select (count(*)) as 'Counts',country, state
  from dbo.people
  group by country, state
  having count(*)>1 
)
select sum(Counts) + 1 as Counts
from initial_query
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc for the answer if I need to order it by name then do i need to use row_number in the subquery

Comment: @csharpdev why would you want to order a sum ?, maybe if you show us the result that you want to get, we can help you to achieve it.

Comment: Hi Marc,
for example like if year= 16 Aug 2019, I need to find the count of all the dates lesser than that date
i.e '2019-05-04'  for  the same year
count will come as 1  
and then add 1 to the count

select count(*), years from [practice].[dbo].[People]
group by years
order by years desc

Count years
1   2020-08-11
1    2020-07-11
1   2019-09-01
1   2019-08-16
1  2019-05-04
1  2018-06-11